# Flags page layout bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, design

The layout of the flagging page (SO) has changed and now the sidebar has dropped to the bottom of the page.

Looks like the flagged posts are much wider now, resulting in the sidebar not having enough space anymore.

Chrome 1280*1024

[image]

Comment: Mind uploading a screenshot?

Comment: @Sathya - done.

Comment: fixed in latest ... trying to figure out when we will deploy

Comment: this should now be deployed, btw

Comment: @MarcGravell - Saw that, thanks :)