# Display bug for long text on flags page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, design

Probably an edge case, but when a flagged answer has an extremely long line of text, it messes up the entire layout for the "Flags" page:

[image]

As you can see the `$googleCodes` array is so long (and has no spaces) that it does not wrap, causing a horizontal scrollbar. It also pushes the "What is this" header to the bottom of the screen:

[image]

This may be related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111016/flags-page-layout-bug#), which is marked resolved.

I'm on Google Chrome on Windows 7 with 1440x900 resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call this obsolete.  The design of the site has had many changes since this was posted, and I was unable to find or cause an example of a post that caused page elements to shift out of view (or at all).